# A short story involving time travel induced by a potion/tablet/medicine

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, potions

In the mid 1970s I read a short story on time travel. Pretty sure it was English, ie. written and set in England early twentieth century perhaps  Scotland.

It was slightly quirky in that it described the result of a potion or tablet or medicine where your experience of movement didn’t appear affected, but everything else, especially people appeared to be moving very slowly.

Pretty sure kids/young adults book of short stories and the main character was a boy. I reckon it asked the people doing this to consider the side affect of rapid aging.

That’s it, the biggest impact I recall was it made me think of things from a different perspective and to use anything special you may have with care.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You might try checking out the [guide to writing good identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) in case it triggers some additional details.  If I understand your question correctly, actual time _travel_ isn't involved, just a different experience of time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There have been quite a few stories on that theme, but given the early twentieth century English setting, you may be thinking of ["The New Accelerator"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54801), a 1901 short story by [H. G. Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._G._Wells), available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/11870/11870-h/11870-h.htm#link2H_4_0028).

Plot summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Accelerator):

> "The New Accelerator" is a 1901 science fiction short story by H. G. Wells. The story addresses an elixir, invented by a Prof. Gibberne, that accelerates all of an individual's physiological and cognitive processes by some orders of magnitude, such that although the individual perceives no change in themselves, the external world appears almost frozen into immobility and only the motion of most rapidly moving objects - such as the tip of a cracked whip - can be perceived.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be *[The House on the Strand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_House_on_the_Strand)* by Daphne du Maurier?

> The setting for the story is an ancient Cornish house called Kilmarth, which is based on the house the author had recently bought, following the death of her husband.[5] The narrator, Dick Young, has given up his job and been offered the use of Kilmarth by an old university friend, Magnus Lane, a leading biophysicist in London. He reluctantly agrees to act as a test subject for a drug that Magnus has secretly developed. On taking it for the first time, Dick finds that it enables him to enter into the landscape around him as it existed during the early 14th century. He becomes drawn into the lives of the people he sees there and is soon addicted to the experience. Dick finds himself following Roger, who lives at Kilmarth, acts as steward to Sir Henry Champernoune, and is a secret admirer of the beautiful Isolda, wife of Sir Oliver Carminowe. She has been conducting a secret affair with the brother of Sir Henry's wife, Sir Otto Bodrugan, who is waylaid and killed by Oliver's men.

Comment: Do you have any quotes that could improve your answer to this question?

Comment: Thanks but no this isn't the story I read. However, I will read it now!